# Performant Postgres Pagination w/ ability to choose any page

Tags: postgresql, pagination

I have a Postgres database that is starting to grow quite large.  I started off using LIMIT / OFFSET pagination and that's starting to get problematic when they want to load a page with a big Offset.

**This loads fast:**
`SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0`

**This loads slow:**
`SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 10000`

**The Query is generated like this:** `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ${perPage} OFFSET ${(page - 1) * perPage}`

Note that the id field is an index on the table.

I understand that the 2nd query loads slow because with offset it needs to scan all previous records in order to find it's current position.

I was searching for other solutions but they all seem to require you to know the previous position of the previous query `keyset pagination` which makes it impossible to load a specific page as far as I can tell, **being able to load a specific page is a requirement in this case**.

I was reading this article: https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/

And cursor seemed like a good option but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work, I tried modifying existing query but kept getting syntax errors, I'm not sure if cursors run when you run queries and then you run a query on that query.

Essentially I'm trying to find the easiest / fastest way to select a subsection of a PostgresSQL table given a `page` and `perPage` parameter that can scale with large data tables.

Comment: You tried cursors but didn't show us what specifically you tried, and you got syntax errors but don't tell us what the specific error was. What kind of help were you hoping to obtain based on this information?

Comment: [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pagination-problem-total-result-count/) are some alternatives.

Comment: The key question is what kind of write activity is going on for table `users`, that might impact the sort order. If any, "page 142" is not a well defined target, and you need to define requirements for exact page definitions first. If no writes impact leading rows and their `id` values, the task is simple ...

Comment: @jjanes I don't really understand any of the Cursor examples that I've been able to find enough to get a somewhat usable query.  Was hoping for an example similar to the limit & offset example above.

Comment: The example given in the Citus blog works, provided you have the table and column indicated.  It is inherently not a single statement, so I don't know how similar to something which is a single statement it is possible for it to appear.  The offset it implemented with a MOVE command (not shown in the blog), the limit is implemented with a FETCH command.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter what would be a case where writes impact leading rows and their id values? As far as I know our case wouldn't impact that

Comment: @jjanes Is there any way to see a full example? I'm having a difficult time connecting the dots from what the Citus blog is showing.

Comment: Also the ids are sequential but there could be gaps in the ids for deleted rows

Comment: *"deleted rows"* is one impact. How frequent? Concurrently? Are there other operations impacting the paging? How should concurrent operations affect page numbers? Do they matter? You tell us.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Rows are deleted as needed, they are deleted at random whichever row is no longer needed. Ideally all pages should be the same length unless it's the last page.